# How to store PostgreSQL Insert queries rows affected by count in bash variables

Tags: java, linux, bash, postgresql, variables

I have Postgresql queries in .sql file and I am executing that .sql file by running bash script in Amazon Linux instance.

I have to get the count of affected rows by multiple insert/update queries in bash variable.

Following are the sample insert queries from my .sql file.

```
with a as (Insert into demo1(username) values('A'),('B') returning 1)
select count(*) as one from a;


with b as (Insert into demo1(username) values('A'),('B') returning 1)
select count(*) as two from b;
```

This is my script command that I am using to execute the .sql file.

```
VALUE=$(psql -U $DBUSER -h $DBHOST -qAX $DB -f "${SQLFILELOCATION}/test.sql") >> "${LOGFILE}"
echo $VALUE
```

And following is the output string getting stored in the **VALUE** variable.

```
one 2 (1 row) two 2 (1 row)
```

I have to pass this **VALUE** variable to my java program as cmd line argument to generate the report based on affected rows of different tables insert/update queries.

So **HOW to store the affected rows** by multiple queries in bash variable something like the following pattern so that I can process the **VALUE** variable string in my JAVA program?

```
one=2,two=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search more about extracting values from bash output. Typical solutions for this are tools like `sed`, `awk` or using some regexps.

As your output will be all the time same, you can use `awk` positionals parameters:

```
$ VALUE=$(psql -U $DBUSER -h $DBHOST -qAX $DB -f "${SQLFILELOCATION}/test.sql") >> "${LOGFILE}"
$ echo $VALUE
one 2 (1 row) two 2 (1 row)
# 1 2  3   4   5  6  7  8  
$ ONE=$(echo "$VALUE" | awk '{print $2}')
$ TWO=$(echo "$VALUE" | awk '{print $6}')
$ CMD_STRING="one=$ONE,two=$TWO"
$ ./your_java_prog $CMD_STRING
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the output as one string to your java app, then use RegEx to extract what you need.